# Which Boost UTF backend is currently used?

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8

Following the boost manual (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/locale/doc/html/using_localization_backends.html),

I can set a UTF backend using:

```
boost::locale::localization_backend_manager my = boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global();
my.select("std");
```

Is there any way to now check, whether indeed the std backend is used?

I only seem to be able to get all the available backends, but not the currently active one

```
boost::locale::localization_backend_manager lbm = boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global();
auto s = lbm.get_all_backends();
for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](string& x){ cout << x << endl; });
```

Comment: The most I can see is a `get()` on the manager that lets you grab the current backend. However the interface of the backends doesn't provide any way to identify them, and all the implementation is hidden in the compiled part of the library, so you can't even try to cast as the types aren't exposed.

Comment: I think you cannot, at least with use of the static `global()` helper. In case you manually add backends to the list, you might be able to compare the underlying pointers of the returned auto_ptrs. But since the `select()` method may be applied to only a subset of categories _(allows combining different backends)_ , I'm not sure how useful the information is anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. There isn't a way to get the current back-end for a multitude of reasons:

- There's no public API function that gives you access to the back-ends used
- `localization_backend` uses the pimpl idiom to defer the actual implementation of the back-ends. There's no reflection either in `localization_backend` or in the back-ends themselves
- This comment from [`localization_backend.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/locale/blob/develop/include/boost/locale/localization_backend.hpp#L25):

  > Backends are usually registered inside the localization backends
  >   manager and allow transparent support of different backends, so a user
  >   can switch the backend by simply linking the application to the
  >   correct one.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Each backend can be installed with a different default priotiry so
  >   when you work with two different backends, you can specify priotiry so
  >   this backend will be chosen according to their priority.

It would needlessly complicate the implementation as on top of the priority feature, specific back-ends can be set for specific locale categories. `Boost.Locale` is designed to "just work" with whatever back-ends it's configured with, transparency and binary compatibility in mind. As a commenter said, it's not really useful information since you're using this library to abstract away library/platform-specific features.